# How to draw edges between vertices in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graph

I'm developing a logic game which consists in altering a mathematical graph set. The logic of the game has all been coded by my professor, and now I need to implement the graphical interface. I'm looking to achieve something like this:

[image]

So far Ive managed to draw a set of vertices using GL_POINTS. Now I need to add the edges/lines. However, I can't just use GL_LINES or other similar OpenGL primitive as each vertex may have more than onde edge attached to it. Below is my code so far (I'm learning from Ogldev):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b37283c923935dd18fa6

Answer (score 4):

> Now I need to add the edges/lines. However, I can't just use GL_LINES or other similar OpenGL primitive as each vertex may have more than onde edge attached to it.

Of course you'll use GL_LINES for this. OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing API. Vertices are not something that OpenGL keeps track of.

What you want to draw there is called a "graph" and the lines are "edges" between "nodes". You just submit pairs of vertices for each line to draw where each line represents an edge in the graph. You should already have the list of edges. If not, you have to build that first.